# How do I open a dimensional gate?

Tags: the-sims-3

From various source I've come to understand that the PlasmaPunch Gyroscopic Conductor from Showtime can act as a sort of rabbithole, like the time machine or mausoleum.

Are any specific conditions required to bring this to pass, or is it just random chance?

And, as a sub question, if it's random chance, what are the odds?

Comment: What expansion is this from?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Question edited to reflect expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get a Handy Sim to upgrade this object to include the Dimensional Gate. Then you can use the gate at will. :)

Comment: What does it do?